# Adding cell in Table view in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on the table view. In my table view cell i have two textfields in which user enters any data. There is also a button on the table view to add new cell when user click the button. The new cell should look like same as there are previous cell shown. I have tried some code but it isn't working. My code is this,

```
extension FlashCardViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = flashCardTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FlashCardTableViewCell

   cell.termTxt.delegate = self
   cell.definitionTxt.delegate = self
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 115
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    allCellsText.append(textField.text!)
    print(allCellsText)
}
```

}

this is the button code to add new cell,

```
 @IBAction func addCardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: allCellsText.count+1, section: 0)
    flashCardTableView.beginUpdates()
    flashCardTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    flashCardTableView.endUpdates()
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

when i hit the button the app crashes by showing this error,

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

My view looks like this,
[image]

Comment: Number of rows in section has hardcoded value of 5 hence the crash. Correct way to do is make your number of rows dynamic based on count of some array or something like that, when user taps on button modify your data source to include the new cell that should solve your problem,

Comment: Actually, the scenario is that  when my view loads it should show 5 cells with the same views. Afterwards user can add more cell if needed. Thats why i give it hardcoded as 5 to initally show it 5 cell. @SandeepBhandari

Comment: so have a variable with initial value of 5 use that variable as return value in cellForRowAtIndexPath, now when user taps on button increment the variable by 1 and then call begin update, insert row and end update

Comment: can u show this how can we do this? @SandeepBhandari

Comment: Take a look at the answer posted

Comment: i have tried it and stored 5 in a variable and increment the variable and then call  begin update but it is showing this error, *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 6 into section 0, but there are only 5 rows in section 0 after the update'

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5 // wrong
    return allCellsText.count // correct

}
```

You are only inserting new cell but not providing sufficient info to `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Update 1:

```
func numberOfSections {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 5
    } else {
        return allCellsText.count
    }

}


@IBAction func addCardBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: allCellsText.count+1, section: 1) // section 1
    flashCardTableView.beginUpdates()
    flashCardTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    flashCardTableView.endUpdates()
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: allCellsText.count is empty initally.

Comment: Then you have to keep the count of existing cells or separate them in sections.

Comment: how can i keep it seperate count for cell? @Mr.Bista

Comment: check updated answer, will give you some general idea on that